# got the most large data based on field

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to retrieve data from the sample table that I have, based on the field `new_id` greatest .

```
    date    |   name  |    new_id   |  
----------- | ------- | ----------- |
2013-01-10  |  jimmy  |      1      | 
2014-01-10  |  jimmy  |      2      | 
2015-01-10  |  jimmy  |      3      | 
2016-01-10  |  jimmy  |      4      |  
2015-01-10  |  smith  |      1      | 
2016-01-10  |  smith  |      2      | 
2016-01-10  |  johny  |      1      |  
2015-01-10  |  johny  |      2      | 
2016-01-10  |  johny  |      3      |
```

expected results

```
    date    |   name  |    new_id   |  
----------- | ------- | ----------- |
2013-01-10  |  jimmy  |      4      | 
2014-01-10  |  smith  |      2      | 
2015-01-10  |  johny  |      3      |
```

I 've tried but it was not as I expected

This My Controller

```
$data=array('getaDta'   => $this->m_model->mData(),
                'content'       =>'home/dashboard');        
$this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
```

My m_model

```
function mData() {  
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('myTable'); 
    $this->db->select_max('new_id');
    $this->db->where('new_id',);        
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();                                    
}
```

views

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>New ID</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($getaDta as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->new_id; ?></td>
            </tr>       
        <?php }?>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you showing `2016-01-10  |  smith  |      2` when there is `2015-01-10  |  johny  |      2` too with `id=2`?

Comment: @NanaPartykar, I want to get a name that has the highest new_id

Comment: But, Johny is also having 2 as new_id. Then why showing smith data only. That's my question.

Comment: you want to get all latest records using new_id field ? with maximum 1 record per new_id field .. please confirm.

Comment: @Mit.agile, Yes, it is true

Comment: @NanaPartykar, I expect from the `name` that appeared to have the highest value `new_id`.

Comment: try this **SELECT * FROM (SELECT  id, date,name, new_id FROM sample_table
ORDER BY id DESC) as temp
GROUP BY new_id**

Comment: @dwiyanto I think your expected result is not correct. Date fields are not corresponding to the original table

Comment: yes i guess he has not shown proper expected result above in his question, however as per understanding i have put above code and tell us if this is what you want.

Comment: thanks @jophab  I want to show only the name with the id of the greatest , but for the date field is not to be displayed

Comment: @Mit.agile I understand your script , but how do I get (max new_id)  of the `name`

Comment: what do you mean by **max new_id of the name** ? what is **name** here ?  do you have another table you want to join with ? if so then you need to use **JOIN QUERY**

Comment: try this query if so **SELECT temp.*,t.name FROM (SELECT  id, testing, new_id FROM sample_table
ORDER BY id DESC) as temp
INNER JOIN tmp t ON t.id = temp.new_id
GROUP BY temp.new_id** here i have added **JOIN query** by adding a new table **tmp** and checking its **id** matches **new_id** from another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will give name and the largest new_id for that name

```
SELECT name, MAX(new_id) FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` in your mysql query. For e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY name;
```